# Manipulating the CSS of a Google Maps marker on tap

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, ionic-framework

Consider the following way to manipulate the CSS layer containing all of my map markers:

http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/f4e5bd78b214ff081254

With the key section of code here;

```js
var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();

myoverlay.draw = function() {
  //this assigns an id to the markerlayer Pane, so it can be referenced by CSS
  this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markerLayer';
};

myoverlay.setMap(map);
```

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(friendMarker, 'click', function() {
  // 'this' is the marker
  console.log("FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: " + this.id)
})
```

I have added a red border around my markers, and now I would like to change that to a green border when a user taps on the marker.

How can I do that in my marker creation loop?

EDIT: Which looks like this;

```js
// SHOW FRIENDS ON MAP

var drawFriendMarkersOnMap = function() {
  Friendship.getAllFriends({
    user_id: user_session.id
  }, function(response) {
    User.friends = response.result
    $rootScope.friends = response.result

    for (var friend in $rootScope.friends) {
      var friendPos = new google.maps.LatLng(
        parseFloat($rootScope.friends[friend].lat),
        parseFloat($rootScope.friends[friend].lon)
      )

      var friendImage = {
        url: 'img/maleavatar.png',
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50)
      }

      var friendMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: friendPos,
        map: map,
        title: $rootScope.friends[friend].first,
        id: $rootScope.friends[friend].id,
        icon: friendImage,
        optimized: false
      })

      google.maps.event.addListener(friendMarker, 'click', function() {
        // 'this' is the marker
        console.log("FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: " + this.id)
      })
    }
  })
}

drawFriendMarkersOnMap()

// HANDLE CSS STYLING OF MARKERS

// http://bl.ocks.org/amenadiel/f4e5bd78b214ff081254
var myoverlay = new google.maps.OverlayView()
myoverlay.draw = function() {
  //this assigns an id to the markerlayer Pane, so it can be referenced by CSS
  this.getPanes().markerLayer.id = 'markerLayer'
}
myoverlay.setMap(map)
```

CSS

```css
/* Map marker styling */

#markerLayer img {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `this` is the right element as you indicated:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(friendMarker, 'click', function() { 
document.getElementById(this).style.border = "2px solid green !important";
})
```

Comment: "Cannot read property 'style' of null", since 'this' references the marker object that the google maps api consumes, and not the actual <div> containing marker html.

Comment: What does this give you then: `console.log("FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: " + this.id)`

Comment: It gives me the id of my marker, which I defined when I created each one of them. `var friendMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: friendPos,
                    map: map,
                    title: $rootScope.friends[friend].first,
                    id: $rootScope.friends[friend].id,
                    icon: friendImage,
                    optimized: false
                })`

Comment: Does this make a difference: `document.getElementById(this.id).style.border = "2px solid green !important";`

Comment: There is no `this` in my DOM, so it cannot be referenced with document.getElementById, that's why this is kind of difficult. I can style all my markers with the blanket 'markerLayer', but I don't know how to target particular ones.

Comment: I'm with you. Looking at the d3.js page, it adds a single div with a single id with all the markers and their borders within that. The markers and the overlay don't have their own unique ids (or classes). I'm thinking that you'd have to change the way the overlay is added so it maybe adds multiple layers (one per marker) or unique ids to each. What does this look like: "How can I do that in my marker creation loop?"

Comment: Added the marker creation loop to the main question, plus the overlay thing.

Comment: Where's the CSS for adding the borders around the markers? When does this happen? Wondering if you need to move your listener to after adding the map layer.

Comment: The CSS is sitting in my general style.css, `/* Map marker styling */
#markerLayer img {
  border: 2px solid white !important;
  width: 50px !important;
  height: 50px !important;
  border-radius: 100%;
}` I think it automatically is applied because of that overlay draw function, but I don't know when in particular, maybe after the markers are added it draws over them?

Comment: When you get this `id` from here `console.log("FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: " + this.id)` have you tried putting that into this statement in place of the `this` --> `document.getElementById(this).style.border = "2px solid green !important";`

Comment: Do you mean like this? `google.maps.event.addListener(friendMarker, 'click', function() {
                    // 'this' is the marker
                    console.log("FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: " + this.id)
                    document.getElementById(this).style.border = "2px solid green !important";
                })` or do you mean putting the ID in it?

Comment: No...what does this actually return: `console.log("FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: " + this.id) `

Comment: It returns `FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: 3
FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: 2
FRIEND MARKER TAPPED: 7` so the id is getting assigned to... something in the DOM I think.

Comment: I think we might need the multiple overlays approach.

Comment: Just for fun, try this: `google.maps.event.addListener(friendMarker, 'click', function() {  document.getElementById('#3').style.border = "2px solid green !important"; })`

Comment: Sorry...meant this: `google.maps.event.addListener(friendMarker, 'click', function() { document.getElementById('3').style.border = "2px solid green !important"; })`

Comment: Still getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: Even with `3` replaced with `this.id`, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

Comment: What if you move that all until later in your code...after this: `myoverlay.setMap(map)`

Comment: I moved it to later in my code, still getting a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`